# Transform xml using xslt in python

Tags: python, xml, xslt

I have seen the example and solution in the website but my coding still have some problem. I dont know how to change it.
This is my xml coding which save as testing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Menu>
 <Title>Snacks</Title>
 <Icecreams>
 <Icecream>Nutella brownie</Icecream>
 <Icecream>Blackcurrent</Icecream>
 </Icecreams>
 <Beverages>
 <Beverage>Fresh Mango Shake</Beverage>
 <Beverage>Cold coffee</Beverage>
 </Beverages>
<Title>Starters</Title>
 <NonvegStarter>
 <Nonveg>Chilly chicken</Nonveg>
 <Nonveg>Chicken Urwal</Nonveg>
 </NonvegStarter>
 <vegStarter>
 <veg>Veg Manchurian</veg>
 <veg>Spring roll</veg>
 </vegStarter>
</Menu>
```

And this is my xsl coding save as testing.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
 <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />
<xsl:template match="/">
 Menu:<xsl:value-of select="/Menu/Title"/>
 Icecreams: <xsl:apply-templates select="/Menu/Icecreams/Icecream"/>
 </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Icecream">
 — <xsl:value-of select="." />
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I use the recommend coding which is

```
import lxml.etree as ET

dom = ET.parse(testing.xml)
xslt = ET.parse(testing.xsl)
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
print(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
```

And it will output the error with "name "testing" is not defined"

Comment: The error seems to be related to python, not to XSLT - I think you should tag your question accordingly. Re your stylesheet, it too will error out because you have smart quotes instead of plain ones.

Comment: Ya sorry, i changed for the smart quotes but still have the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ET.parse(testing.xml)` should be `ET.parse('testing.xml')`. The same change needs to be done for the second line.

I don't understand what you want to achieve with `print(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))` with output method `text` in the XSLT.

Anyway, the lxml documentation suggestes using `newdom.write_output` e.g. `newdom.write_output('result.txt')` is a better way to deal with outputting XSLT transformation results.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help with the answer, for the newdom.write_output, i added it and it will show the error with "LookupError: unknown encoding: '' "

Comment: Does using an `<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="text"/>` in the XSLT improve things and make the error about the unknown encoding go away?

Comment: yes! Thank you very much. It run successfully.